# Hubot not setting up properly: "hubot-redis-brain: using default redis..."

Tags: linux, hubot, campfire

I have looked at the information on Hubot on their own actual website, I have tried everything, I have been on this problem for nearly just over a day and a half worth of hours.

I am installing Hubot on a **Virtual Machine using Linux**, I would like to get it **working alongside Campfire**.

So far I have set up the Hubot, set my own personal details for the bot, it is called Tron.

I have then went to **export the TOKEN**,

I **exported the ROOMS** as

"
 `export HUBOT_CAMPFIRE_ROOMS="123456"`"

I then **exported the account**: "`export HUBOT_CAMPFIRE_ACCOUNT="place121"`"

It has given me this error:
"`INFO hubot-redist-brain: using default redis on localhost:6379`"

How can I fix this?

I am quite frankly fed up, this software clearly isn't fully operational, either due to the tutorial information or the software itself. I was up late trying to get it working.

The tutorial information on there is so **vague** the software should be pulled down and someone should make a **clear tutorial** on how to properly install it, none of these vague commands.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your instance of Hubot is persisting the Hubot brain (data store) in Redis. This requires a running Redis instance and an environment variable providing the connection string to Redis with authentication details. The [hubot-redis-brain GitHub repo](https://github.com/hubot-scripts/hubot-redis-brain) details the required setup.

Comment: I managed to get it working by removing 'Redis' and 'Heroku' dependencies from one of the script files

Comment: That works too, just note that your Hubot brain is now volatile, so it will start like new every run.

Comment: I noticed that, I then installed Redis, after I close the terminal it keeps erasing any campfire stuff, so I just pasted the token, room and account in the bin/hubot hubot.sh file and it works

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by commands, could you please clarify a bit?

Comment: as in the token, room and account? I should have said arguments, grammatical mistake

Comment: Ah, so the environment variables and arguments can be set in a script that then calls the hubot script.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of putting it on Github and it trying to find the info from a txt doc on there but if Redis does the same job

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, the Hubot brain only stores things it needs at runtime about users etc. Configuration details should be put in a script, putting that token on Github is a security risk since it lets anyone connect to your instance. A script with read permissions only for the user you're running Hubot as would be more secure.